# How to use F-score as error function to train neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, precision-recall

I am pretty new to neural networks. I am training a network in tensorflow, but the number of positive examples is much much less than negative examples in my dataset (it is a medical dataset). 
So, I know that F-score calculated from precision and recall is a good measure of how well the model is trained. 
I have used error functions like cross-entropy loss or MSE before, but they are all based on accuracy calculation (if I am not wrong). But how do I use this F-score as an error function? Is there a tensorflow function for that? Or I have to create a new one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing model evaluation metrics for classification with training losses.

Accuracy, precision, F-scores etc. are evaluation metrics computed from binary outcomes and binary predictions.

For model training, you need a function that compares a continuous score (your model output) with a binary outcome - like cross-entropy. Ideally, this is calibrated such that it is minimised if the predicted mean matches the population mean (given covariates). These rules are called [proper scoring rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule), and the cross-entropy is one of them.

Also check the thread [is-accuracy-an-improper-scoring-rule-in-a-binary-classification-setting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359909/is-accuracy-an-improper-scoring-rule-in-a-binary-classification-setting)

If you want to weigh positive and negative cases differently, two methods are

- oversample the minority class and correct predicted probabilities when predicting on new examples. For fancier methods, check the under sampling module of [`imbalanced-learn`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) to get an overview.
- use a different proper scoring rule for training loss. This allows to e.g. build in asymmetry in how you treat positive and negative cases while preserving calibration. [Here](https://www.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/Gneiting2007jasa.pdf) is review of the subject.

I recommend just using simple oversampling in practice.

Answer (score 8):

It appears approaches for optimising directly for these types of metrics have been devised and used successfully, improving scoring and or training times:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/human-protein-atlas-image-classification/discussion/77289

https://www.kaggle.com/c/human-protein-atlas-image-classification/discussion/70328

https://www.kaggle.com/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric

One such method involves using the sums of probabilities, in place of counts, for the sets of true positives, false positives, and false negative metrics. For example F-beta loss (the generalisation of F1) can be calculated in with Torch in Python as follows:

```
def forward(self, y_logits, y_true):
    y_pred = self.sigmoid(y_logits)
    TP = (y_pred * y_true).sum(dim=1)
    FP = ((1 - y_pred) * y_true).sum(dim=1)
    FN = (y_pred * (1 - y_true)).sum(dim=1)
    fbeta = (1 + self.beta**2) * TP / ((1 + self.beta**2) * TP + (self.beta**2) * FN + FP + self.epsilon)
    fbeta = fbeta.clamp(min=self.epsilon, max=1 - self.epsilon)
    return 1 - fbeta.mean()
```

An alternative method is described in this paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04802

The approach taken optimises for a lower bound on the statistic. Other metrics such as AUROC and AUCPR are also discussed. An implementation in TF of such an approach can be found here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/global_objectives

Comment: Hi, the github link dosent seem to work. Is there anyplace I can find the code for this for tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

the loss value and accuracy is a different concept. The loss value is used for training the NN. However, accuracy or other metrics is to value the training result.